Difference in Difference or HLM/Mixed Effects Model?
I am working on evaluating a high school intervention. A group of 14-16 9th grade students are recruited each year to do attend a local college part time. I would like to understand how this impacts their GPA, college credits earned, and college enrollment rates. For a comparison group, I have access to the entire district's data (where the treatment students come from) and will use propensity score matching to create a comparison group for each cohort of students along 6-7 variables and establish baseline equivalence with three years of previous data (test scores, attendance, discipline, etc.).
I am trying to figure out which analysis to propose to compare these two groups. At first I was thinking a Difference in Difference model but since they are in cohorts, time might be a variable i need to take into account, as the program itself might be implemented with more fidelity as each cohort joins. So then would I need a nested model, like HLM/mixed effects? Or should I propose running both, one to account for the cohorts and one to measure the overall effects of the program? Or something else entirely, like a repeated measures ANOVA? I am also concerned about the relatively small group sizes...
